# Why Widget like Checkbox does not maintain its state by itself?

Tags: flutter, state

I am trying to create a custom Checkbox.
 so, I took a look at the [Material Design checkbox code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html) and I found that checkbox Does not update its state by itself when its value updates..
so here we have to rebuild the parent widget in order to rebuild checkbox widget :
This is how they are suggesting to use it in the documentation:

```
build(context) =>
  Column(
      children:[
        widget1(),
        widget2(),
        Checkbox(
          value: _throwShotAway,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
             setState(() {
               _throwShotAway = newValue;
              });
          },
       )   
      ]
  );
```

**Question**: Would it be better if we handled state changes internally without rebuilding parent widget?

Comment: Most widgets that use a checkbox will listen for the onChanged callback and rebuild the checkbox with a new value to update the visual appearance of the checkbox. line in the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html

Comment: This is what I mean, I only need to rebuild checkbox why would I rebuild the whole parent..

Comment: yeah so it will not rebuild your whole parent

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, setState() which is used in parent will rebuild the parent too..

Comment: please paste  the whole code so I will get idea

Comment: Just Consider `Parent` as a widget that has a subtree of widgets in addtion to checkbox..

Comment: according to standards its not rebuild your whole parent please run again and see the results

Comment: I added a checkpoint on the build function, and it is being rebuilt every time i click on the checkbox

Comment: Please post your whole code I didn't get  exzat idea

Comment: I can not because It will be complicated, I am just tryin to simplify it.. just consider this build function the parent's build function that's getting rebuilt  everytime i click checkbox.. there is nothing else to consider here.